# Kata : Take a ten minute Walk

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was doing some training(i am recently newbie to js) and a was trying to make one [exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/take-a-ten-minute-walk/discuss/javascript) (the posted one) and I have a question:
I handeled to make it work like this:
This is the case:

Tests fails when it reachs the last ternay operation condition, Could you help me explaininng why?? I really will appreciate it.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: What is a valid walk?

Comment: This is a classic case for switch/case (pan intended).

Comment: Sorry now I added the descripcion

Comment: Use a switch/case statement

Comment: And that's all? Ill look for info about else if versus switch/case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to tweak the code as follows:

```
element == 'n' ? vertical += 1 :
  element == 's' ? vertical -= 1 :
  element == 'w' ? horizontal += 1 : horizontal -= 1
```

Only the 'e' element remains, and for it no longer needs an additional condition, we immediately write that it returns with 'false'

//  element == 'e' ? element -= 1 - *it's too much*

Comment: Yes that was what I was trying, I didnt pay enough attention, my fault , thank you!